# Game control bindings dictionary with delegates

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, game-engine, key-bindings

My game has a property of type `IInput`:

```
private IInput Input;
```

Before the game loop, I add some key bindings like this:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    input.BindKey( Keys.Escape, Exit );
    // etc...
}
```

The `BindKey` method adds an item to the key bindings dictionary of the `Input` class:

```
internal class Input : IInput
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Keys, Action> keyBindings;

    public void BindKey( Keys key, Action action )
    {
        keyBindings.Add( key, action );
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        // update keyboard state...            

        foreach ( var binding in keyBindings )
        {
            if ( keyboard.IsKeyDown( binding.Key )
            {
                binding.Value();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Process` method is called during the game loop. This works well, but I would like to bind a key to a method that accepts a parameter, ala:

```
input.BindKey( Keys.W, Move( Directions.Up ) );
```

How can I do this? I tried changing the `keyBindings` property of the `Input` class:

```
private readonly IDictionary<Keys, Delegate> keyBindings;
```

This requires me to change my original bindings to:

```
input.BindKey( Keys.Escape, new Action( Exit ) );
```

But a similar approach doesn't work for binding methods with parameters:

```
// compiler error: "Method name is expected"
input.BindKey( Keys.W, new Func<Directions>( Move( Directions.Up ) ) );

// compiler error: "Delegate constructor is invoked with 2 argument(s)"
input.BindKey( Keys.W, new Func<Directions>( Move, Directions.Up ) );
```

This doesn't work either:

```
// compiler error: "Argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Delegate'"
input.BindKey( Keys.W, x => Move( Vector2.Zero ) );
```

**EDIT**

I was using `Func` incorrectly. I want to supply the direction to a method, but I don't care what it returns. I'm not getting very far with this either:

```
// 1. Cannot use "void" as a type argument
// 2. Method name is expected
input.BindKey( Keys.W, new Func<Vector2, void>( Move( Directions.Up ) );

// Cannot apply operator ">" to operands of type "null" and "void"
input.BindKey( Keys.W, new Func<Vector2, null>( Move( Directions.Up ) );
```

Even if I change the `Move` method to return true:

```
// Method name is expected
input.BindKey( Keys.W, new Func<Vector2, bool>( Move( Directions.Up ) );
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with `Func`? Is it going to return s.t? What you've written there `Func<Dictionary>`, expects a method with no parameters which returns a `Dictionary`!

Comment: Unfortunately, you aren't going to have much luck with this, since delegates can't change their number of arguments/return values dynamically like that. I'd suggest that you make the called Action do whatever assignment. A friend and I have actually been doing something very similar, though behind an extra abstraction layer of flags enum Buttons, and a queue which recognizes sequences of recently pressed buttons and matches them to the correct delegate. Be warned if you try that, it isn't easy.

Comment: @ArinGhazarian simply because I thought I needed to use `Func`.

Comment: @davidkennedy85, Ok if so, then your want a delegate that accepts a method as input and returns the Direction, right?

Comment: I don't necessarily care if the method returns anything. I want to give it the direction to move in.

Comment: Just remember that you can use a lambda to assign an Action, and have the lambda call a Func and assign it's result to a field. Just be careful.

Comment: @ArinGhazarian whoops, see edit.

Comment: @Magus I'm having a hard time parsing that. I don't suppose you could give me an example? Also, why do I need to be careful?

Comment: Basically, you can do something like `Action action = () => _ownerPositionVector = Move(Direction.Left);`. The action will assign the field when executed, based on how move is called. It's no more dangerous than a method doing that, except that you may not expect it to happen. I personally think it's quite cool. My whole control scheme is based around it, which allows me to change the states of things implicitly without boolean flags, by simply changing the bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept here is, using the delegation, you'e just pointing to a method which accepts an input parameter, so it won't work like what you've written in your code, the parameter should be passed during invocation! So as a workaround you can write st. like this:

```
internal class Input : IInput
{
  private readonly IDictionary<Keys, Tuple<Action<Directions>, Directions>> keyBindings;
  public void BindKey( Keys key, Tuple<Action<Directions>, Directions> action)
  {
    keyBindings.Add( key, action );
  }

  public void Process()
  {
    // update keyboard state...            

    foreach ( var binding in keyBindings )
    {
        if ( keyboard.IsKeyDown( binding.Key )
        {
            binding.Value.Item1(binding.Value.Item2);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Use `input.BindKey` like this:

```
input.BindKey(Keys.W, Tuple.Create<Action<Directions>, Directions>(Move, Directions.Up));
```

**EDIT:**
You can even do that with you original `Input` class and instead of pointing to the `Move` method, you can create a delegate to do it for you (s.t like @Magus said in the comments) like this:

```
input.BindKey(Keys.W, () => Move(Directions.Up));
```

this way, during the invocation, this delate will be invoked and in turn as you can see it invokes the `Move` method with required parameter.

Comment: I think his main issue was that he has N parameters and may or may not return anything.

Comment: This `input.BindKey(Keys.W, () => Move(Directions.Up));` is just what I was looking for!